# Formatting Highchart's Date in Tooltip Causes Values to Change

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts to plot some points that occur within one day. When I use the defaults the x-axis labels are correct: `12AM, 4AM, 8AM, 12PM, 4PM and 8PM,` and the times echoed in the tooltip for each point are also correct, e.g. Jan 6, 0400, Jan 6 1200, Jan 6, 1600, etc.

I don't want the military time (e.g. 1600 for the hour) so I change the time format via:

`tooltip: {xDateFormat: '%b %e, %l %p' }`

which I thought would result in Jan 6, 4 PM.

But what happens when I do this is that, the labels on the x-axis all become 12 AM and the tooltip look like Jan 6, 00:00:00.016. The points themselves appear in the same spots, it's just that the labels and tooltips are wrong; it seems that the times are now in milliseconds from 12AM.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: When I try with the following example it works as you expected: http://jsfiddle.net/qCUjT/97/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Highcharts.dateFormat(); http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat()

Comment: I am currently using Highcharts.dateFormat to format my x-axis labels (within a 'formatter:' callback)  but I can't figure out how to use it for formatting the time in the tooltips. Should I use it as input to the "tooltip: xDateFormat:" options or should I use it with the 'formatter:' option instead? I have tried all sorts of combinations (the downside of having so many options!) and so far can't get anything to work. Can someone give me a specific example on how to set this up? Thanks.